# How to optimize such codes as follows in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a user-own metric to implement as follows:

```
def metric(pred:pd.DataFrame(), valid:pd.DataFrame()):
    date_begin = valid.dt.min()
    date_end = valid.dt.max()
    x = valid[valid.label == 1].dt.min()

    # p
    p_n_tpp_df = valid[(valid.dt >= x) &\
                       (valid.dt <= x + timedelta(days=30)) &\
                       (p_n_tpp_df.label == 1)]
    p_n_pp_df =  valid[(valid.dt >= date_begin + timedelta(days=30)) &\ 
                       (valid.dt <= date_end + timedelta(days=30)) &\
                       (p_n_tpp_df.label == 1)]


    p_n_tpp = len([x for x in pred.serial_number.values\ 
                     if x in p_n_tpp_df.serial_number.unique()])
    p_n_pp = len([x for x in pred.serial_number.values\ 
                    if x in p_n_pp_df.serial_number.unique()])

    p = p_n_tpp / p_n_pp
    print('p: ', p)

    # r
    p_n_tpr_df = valid[(valid.dt >= date_begin - timedelta(days=30)) &\ 
                      (valid.dt <= date_end - timedelta(days=30)) &\
                      (p_n_tpr_df.label == 1)]
    p_n_pr_df = valid[(valid.dt >= date_begin) &\ 
                      (valid.dt <= date_end) &\ 
                      (p_n_pr_df.label == 1)]


    p_n_tpr = len([x for x in pred.serial_number.values\
                     if x in p_n_tpr_df.serial_number.unique()])
    p_n_pr = len([x for x in pred.serial_number.values\
                    if x in p_n_pr_df.serial_number.unique()])

    r = p_n_tpr / p_n_pr
    print('p: ', r)

    m = 2 * p * r / (p + r)

    return m
```

The `pd.DataFrame()` of `pred` and `valid` have the same columns and `dt` has no intersections. 
And the all the values of `serial_number` in `valid` is a subset of all the values of `serial_number` in `pred`.
The `label` column only has 2 values: 0 or 1.
Here is the sample of `pred` and `valid` is as follows:

```
print(pred.head(3))
    serial_number  dt          label  
0   123            2011-03-21  1
1   52             2011-03-22  0
2   12             2011-03-01  1
..., ...


print(pred.info())
Int64Index: 10000000 entries,
Data columns (total 3 columns):
serial_number  int32
dt             datetimes64[ns]
label          int8
..., ...

print(valid.head(3))
    serial_number  dt          label  
0   324            2011-04-22  1
1   52             2011-04-22  0
2   14             2011-04-01  1
..., ...


print(valid.info())
Int64Index: 10000000 entries,
Data columns (total 3 columns):
serial_number  int32
dt             datetimes64[ns]
label          int8
```

And the size of input `pd.DataFrame` is about 10, 000, 000 samples and 3 features.
When I try to use it to calculate this metric, it is really slow and time spending is more than 2 hours on Intel 9600KF.
So I am wondering how to optimize such code on time cost.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataset?

Comment: should `number` be `serial_number`?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin The sample of dataset is just like the `print(pred.head(3))`  output. And `number` is same as the `serial_number`, I just correct it.

Comment: To help you out, we need a sample of both `pred` and `valid`

Comment: @ItamarMushkin I have updated the details of it. Thanks for your tips.

Comment: Can you format your code such that you do not have to scroll to read the lines? That will make the question more approachable.

Comment: Could you say something about your expectations for speed-up?  About 2h = 120m now and you expect it to become how many minutes?

Comment: Could you also explain what  `...dt has no intersections` means

Comment: The names `p_n_tpp_df.label`, `p_n_tpr_df.label`, `p_n_pr_df.label` are used before defined. How are they first set?  A working example with a real but minimal data set would help transform this form an enigma to a question ;)

Comment: Although a bit unrelated, your use of type annotations (`pred:pd.DataFrame()`) is not correct. Type annotations should be, well, types, but I believe `pd.DataFrame()` creates an instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the biggest performance win in the code that you have:

#### Numpy set logic

```
len([x for x in pred.serial_number.values\
                     if x in p_n_tpr_df.serial_number.unique()])
```

Any line that looks like this is getting the size of the set intersection of `pred.serial_number` and `p_n_tpr_df.serial_number`. Using numpy rather than the list comprehension and the `unique` call will save substantial compute time:

```
intersect_size = np.intersect1d(pred.serial_number.values,
                                p_n_tpr_df.serial_number.values).shape[0]
```

Comment: @bowen-peng did this work for you and if so can you accept this answer?